# How is depletion region of the negatively biased photodiode is re-filled with electrons?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

We were taught that the photons' energy rips off the electrons away from their orbits in the atoms residing inside the depletion region of a negatively biased photodetector. My naive understanding is that at some point all the atoms in the depletion region will lose the electrons and the photocurrent ceises. Why is this thought experiment wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> > Why is this thought experiment wrong?

It's wrong because you're looking at the photodiode as it's own complete system.  It's not.  It's connected to some voltage source (e.g. a battery).

Another way to look at the diode, maybe an easier thought experiment, is consider the photons are not "knocking electrons free".  What they are doing is giving some electrons enough energy to overcome the voltage barrier that exists between the semiconductor junctions.  They leave behind holes which are readily filled by the connected circuit.

So the diode is really *allowing current to flow*.  No external circuit, no current.